How to fetch the total number of products in a category in Amazon's SP-API?
Okay, so I notice there are tools like Rocket Source and Scan Unlimited that are able to find the total number of products in a specific category, and on basis of that, they tell a % chance of how well/frequently a product can sell.
Basically, they divide that product's sales rank with the rest of the products' sales ranks in that specific category.
I'm quite intrigued if Catalog-Items or any other Sub-API in SP-API has the ability to get these numbers?
Looked up throughout the SP-API documentation, and couldn't find the right answer.

As far as I know, there is no way to get that number.
The only way I can think about is to generate ASIN and try to call the getCatalogItem.
Unfortunately it will take you a lot of time and it may not be feasible at all.
